# How to use highcharts(highstock) to display year-week format data？

Tags: highcharts

In fact,my data is weekly data.
This data is from the 1st week to the fiftieth week in 2015 year.

```
data: [
        1884,2936,2039,1948,1814,2071,2183,3234,3426,2188
       ,1884,2936,2039,1948,1814,2071,2183,3234,3426,2188
       ,1884,2936,2039,1948,1814,2071,2183,3234,3426,2188
       ,1884,2936,2039,1948,1814,2071,2183,3234,3426,2188
       ,1884,2936,2039,1948,1814,2071,2183,3234,3426,2188
    ]
```

**I want to show the first week to fiftieth weeks in 2015 on the X axis，but how to modify my code?**

**I do not find the year-week format data for "pointStart",and how to set "pointInterval" value is weekly?**

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="icon" href="https://static.jianshukeji.com/highcharts/images/favicon.ico">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">    
<script src="https://img.hcharts.cn/jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://img.hcharts.cn/highstock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://img.hcharts.cn/highcharts/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://img.hcharts.cn/highcharts-plugins/highcharts-zh_EN.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 600px"></div>
    <script>
    $(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
            chart: {
                zoomType: 'xy'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'test'
            },

            yAxis: {
                scrollbar: {
                    enabled: true,
                    showFull: false
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                split: false
            },

            series: [{
                name:'emloyee1',
                data: [
                  1884,2936,2039,1948,1814,2071,2183,3234,3426,2188
                 ,1884,2936,2039,1948,1814,2071,2183,3234,3426,2188
                 ,1884,2936,2039,1948,1814,2071,2183,3234,3426,2188
                 ,1884,2936,2039,1948,1814,2071,2183,3234,3426,2188
                 ,1884,2936,2039,1948,1814,2071,2183,3234,3426,2188
                ],
                pointStart: Date.UTC(2015,0, 1),
                pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 * 7
            }]
        });

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**The effect of my code：**
[image]

Comment: this reference may help you:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9849806/data-grouping-into-weekly-monthly-by-user

Answer (score 1):

<del>check [data-grouping](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/data-grouping) and set container `min-width`</del>

```
 dataGrouping: {
    forced: true,
    units: [
      ['week', [1]]
    ]
  }
```

<del>[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ywoae7mf/) demo</del>

Your requirement is exactly resolved in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17853889/3898339) post

Comment: Hi,Sir! In fact,I want X axis displays week,likes this "2015-01(week),2015-02(week),……2015-52(week)".When I modified my code like you,the X axis always displays year-month format,why?How to set min-width?

Comment: it is chart container width `<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 1000px"></div>
`